# How long can I store extracted RNA?

Tags: molecular-biology, rna, lab-techniques

If I extract RNA from a (leaf tissue) sample using a one-step phenol:chloroform extraction, how long can those samples be stored at -80°C? And how many times can I defrost and refreeze them before they will become degraded?

Comment: I'd guess that this will depend heavily on the purification of the sample, pure RNA (no Mg2+ e.g) can be stored for a very long time at lower temperatures. Pure RNA in water can be stable for months at 4°C. Freezing and thawing RNA can affect the folding (for RNA with important tertiary structure) as I have observed.

Comment: If you're worried about freeze/thaw cycling, aliquot them into multiple tubes -- that way you only thaw what you need to use.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've found that extracted RNA using commercial kits has stayed stable for many years at -80 C. I would certainly aliquot it before freezing however as RNA is particularly sensitive to freeze-thaw cleavage.

Comment: We've actually checked the degradation of viral RNA extracts, and they will for the most part hold up for more than a year at -80.  We did see more stability variation correlating to sequence than we expected, however.

Comment: This is interesting - how did you measure the degradation? I imagine degradation that might have a significant effect on, for example, RNASeq, would not show on a gel.

Answer (score 3):

We can keep extracted RNA in -80°C for a few weeks, but before the start of any experiments, it needs to be validated by gel electrophoresis.

Answer (score 1):

I keep my RNA in 1mM sodium citrate pH 6.4. Citrate is a chelator, and helps trap the divalent metals many RNAses need to work. The lower pH also helps inhibit RNAse activity. EDTA could work as a chelator, but it only chelates well at pH's where RNAse activity is worse. Citrate gives both chelation and low pH.

Of course I also keep my RNA at -80.

Comment: Do you need to do anything special to remove the citrate when it comes time to use the RNA, for example to make cDNA?

Comment: I've never noticed any problems, but I've never really checked. Only been working with RNA for a couple months now, and my lab is in an old building with a lot of dust, so RNAse contamination has been a bigger issue than enzyme activity. An isopropanol precipitation should be enough to clean up the RNA before any reactions if citrate proves to be a problem.

Comment: We're also in an old dusty building, and RNase is a problem for us too. Thanks for the tip - I'll check whether it works for RNAseq purposes.