# Does extracted DNA degrade after a certain time period?

Tags: dna

For direct use as template in PCR runs. Chelex 100 5-10% w/v extraction. Without listing the whole protocol, in the end the supernate is decanted off and then stored at 4°C. I was under the impression that this could be stored and later used almost indefinately but two of four samples extracted several months back failed to produce a product (when it was known they should have).

Assuming no mistakes were made and the reactions were the same, is there a technical reason the template would degrade to an unusable point?

Is there a rule of thumb about how long it can reasonably be expected to last?

Comment: Related: http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/973/how-long-can-i-store-extracted-rna

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My rule of thumb for DNA samples (in TE or water) - if I have plans to use it that week, I store at 4C. If I plan on using it within a month, I store at -20C. If I'm not sure when I will use it, I keep multiple aliquots at -80C. DNA can degrade by acid hydrolysis in water, because of contaminating nucleases in the sample, and by multiple freeze/thaw cycles.

Comment: Is there any long term storage option at room temperature? http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/2231/how-to-diy-preserve-pet-dna-today-so-that-it-can-be-used-in-20-years

 -Thanks!

Comment: DNA has a half-life of over 500 years under perfect circumstances. However, DNA degrades over time, and when kept in solution, it is difficult for there to be exactly 0 microbes, DNases or chemicals present which can hydrolyze the helix. It degrades over time and old DNA samples kept even at -20C very frequently show poorer results, especially when it is thawed repeatedly. Primers can also degrade gradually at room temperature, etc.