# How long is DNA stable in a freezer?

Tags: dna

Inspired by the post about [extracting pet DNA](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/2231/how-to-diy-preserve-pet-dna-today-so-that-it-can-be-used-in-20-years), how long would genomic DNA be stable for in a -20°C freezer? It is common practice to store DNA (double-stranded, plasmid) in a -20°C freezer in the lab, but would genomic DNA last longer in a -80°C freezer? With either method, how long would it be stable for?

Comment: It depends on your concentration. More concentrated DNA is more stable.

Comment: Closely related to [this question](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/1106/does-extracted-dna-degrade-after-a-certain-time-period) - if not dupe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the DNA is pure, it should last quite a long time.  If there are enzymes and other biological molecules in there, -80C will work much better.

I think you could keep pure DNA at -20C practically indefinitely.

Purity is the main issue there, also pH stabilized, sealed properly, etc.  That makes all the difference.

Comment: I would say that even at 4°C the stability is fairly high

Comment: I usually keep plasmid minipreps at 4C for months its true.  I think the difference is if the ends of the DNA are sheared or ragged, as in a typical gDNA prep, then it might not be so great to leave it unfrozen.

Answer (score -3):

You can store your DNA for 1 week at -4C and for one month at -20C but with storing DNA over these period of time there is a deduction of 10-15% of yield from your DNA sample.

Comment: Can you provide a citation for this? I am skeptical, because I routinely transfect cells using DNA stocks frozen years ago.